# Reccuring events shows next date(reccuring day date day+1) after editing the event,when am reading these events in javascript,

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-calendar

am trying to fetch reccuring events from SP calendar list in javascript,there am having one issue,when am reading the edited reccurence event in javascript then it shows the next days date in javascript whether in calendar list it shows correctly,My code is as bellow

```
    hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(manageQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
    function Retrieval() {
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL
            var context = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostWebUrl);
            var web = context.get_web(); //Get the Site 
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(ListName); //Get the List based upon the Title
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.ExpandRecurrence = true;
            var items = list.getItems(query);
            ctx.load(items);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
            function onQuerySucceeded() {
                retrieveItems(items);
            }
            function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
        }
    function retrieveItems(items) {
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                   var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
                    var eventDate = currentListItem.get_item('EventDate');
                    var EventId = currentListItem.get_item('ID'); //"Id";
                    var TitleField = currentListItem.get_item('Title'); //"Title";    
                    var LocationField = currentListItem.get_item('Location'); //"Location";    
                    var RecurrenceField = currentListItem.get_item('fRecurrence'); //"fRecurrence";      
                    var EndDateField = currentListItem.get_item('EndDate'); //"EndDate";     
                    var EventTypeField = currentListItem.get_item('EventType'); //"EventType";     
                    var SeriesIdField = currentListItem.get_item('MasterSeriesItemID'); //"MasterSeriesItemID";
                    var recurrenceData = currentListItem.get_item("RecurrenceData");                   
            }
    }
```

this snapp will cleare what am trying say
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching your date as shown below :

```
var dates = currentListItem.get_item('EventDate');
var eventDate = new Date(dates);
```

Its giving me the proper required output with right date and time.. See the screenshots for reference

**Screenshot :1**

[image]

**screenshot 2 :**

[image]
You can see here.. first line where i am showing date fetched directly from list, without any modification has different time. 
But the second line has new Date which converts that in to exact time and date. Hope this will work for you too.